# Calling static DLL for RFID Reader from multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll

I am working on a project that has to monitor multiple RFID readers at the same time. The RFID reader has a DLL file which exposes methods to interact with it. One method is to open a connection to it. When I call the static DLL to connect to a single RFID reader, it works fine. If I run multiple instances of my app they all call the static DLL and connect to different RFID readers fine. However I need to be running only a single instance of my main app and then have individual threads connect to individual RFID readers. But when I do this, the first connection is successful but any other threads are unable to call the DLL as I assume it's in a shared memory space and hence engaged by the first thread. how can I solve this problem?

Here is the DoWork fucntion which is called by Thread.Start

```
public void DoWork()
    {

        __parent.UpdateLog(ReaderIP + ": working.");
        int openresult = 0;
        int frmcomportindex = 0;
        int fOpenComIndex;
        byte fComAdr = Convert.ToByte("FF", 16); // $FF

        //this line works fine for the first thread adn fails for all following threads
        // but works fine if I run multiple instances of my app and get each to connect to a single RFID reader
        openresult = StaticClassReaderB.OpenNetPort(ReaderPort, ReaderIP, ref fComAdr, ref frmcomportindex);
        fOpenComIndex = frmcomportindex;
```

Comment: Check out this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

A static variable is a variable which is unique per process. A static method is likely to use static variables, so all calls to a static method that come from the same process are going to use the same data.  A process, of course, can be made up of multiple threads; each and every thread within a process will have the same copy of the static data.

When you use the static DLL from a single process, there is no issue, of course.

When you use the static DLL from multiple processes, there doesn't seem to be an issue, because each process gets its own copy of static data. (Note that there might be a hidden issue if the static methods share system-global resources, like I/O handles).

But when you use the static DLL from a single process with multiple threads, the threads can interfere with each other, because they all share one copy of the static data.

The best way to deal with this is to read the documentation for the static library and follow its recommendations. It is possibility that using the library from multiple threads simply isn't possible. In addition, it is possible that calling it from multiple processes may be causing hidden problems that you're not aware of.